# initializing char * with an expression of type const char

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

```
NSString *query =  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM objects ", catIdS];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *nameChar = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

            NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChar];
       }

       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
```

Semantic issue "initializing char * with an expression of type const char discards qualifiers" in line `char *nameChar = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)`

if change `char *nameChar` to `char *nameChar`
Semantic issue "Sending unsigned char * to parameter of type const char *" converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting it should solve your problem.

```
char *nameChar = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
```

or

```
const unsigned char *nameChar = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
```

Please look at the method's signature,

```
SQLITE_API const unsigned char *sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);
```

Comment: He should use the second of your options since you are not allowed to change the content of the pointer returned by `sqlite3_column_text`.  He'll probably need a cast in `initWithUTF8String:` to cope with the difference in signedness, but it should be safe if the text is really UTF-8.

Comment: @JeremyP. What you say absolutely true for a good practice. But does not complain or do anything wrong even if it is casted or does it?.

Comment: It will still work if you use the former.  It just seems wrong to drop the `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

Use it Like this, it may help

```
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
```

Comment: better implementation than char *nameChar = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1); thanks!