# UTF8String for non const string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, arrays

I found a way to set a string to a char array. I use the following code:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is a string!"];
char *c = [string UTF8String];
```

However, I get the warning, "Initializing 'char *' with an expresion type of 'const char*' discards qualifiers.

It works fine, but I feel like there's a better way to do it, and I'd rather not have a ton of warnings. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [initializing char \* with an expression of type const char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976810/initializing-char-with-an-expression-of-type-const-char).  in other words: the compiler hates it when you slice off the const qualifier like this

Answer (score 3):

The value returned by `[NSString UTF8String]` is a pointer to a constant array of chars. You cannot remove "const" directly.

If you want a non-constant array of chars you must copy the string using the method `strcpy(...)`. You have to declare and initialize an array of chars and then copy the value of the given string inside:

```
NSString *string = @"This is a string";
char cString [string.length]
strcpy(cString, string.UTF8String);
NSLog(@"Copied String: %s", cString);
```

or if you prefer to manage the memory yourself:

```
NSString *string = @"This is a string";
char * cString = malloc(sizeof(char)*string.length);
strcpy(cString, string.UTF8String);
NSLog(@"Copied String: %s", cString);
free(cString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use const char and you can use different types of encoding also:

const char* c = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

```
if (![fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:pathOfDB]) {

    const char *pathDB = [pathOfDB UTF8String];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please give a little more detail on why this answer is useful. You can refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer